# Direct Path to Raw folder to set as ringtone Android

Tags: android, path, ringtone

```
case 64:
                    String path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/data/babysounds/res/raw/laugh.mp3";
                    File ringtoneFile = new File(path);

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtoneFile .getAbsolutePath());
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "laugh");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "The");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile 
                            .getAbsolutePath());
                    getContentResolver().delete(
                            uri,
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                                    + ringtoneFile .getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                            Context.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                            newUri);

                    break;
```

I got this code to set as ringtone but it's not working. What happens: When I click on listView button, file is created but not set as ringtone. 
What I want: I want to get direct path to my raw folder and chose files. How can I do that?
And yes I added permissions

Answer (score 1):

URI or LINK for any resource in the raw folder:

> String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.filename;

Comment: I wrote that, it's working but still doesn't change the ringtone.

Comment: So late, but to set ringtone you have to copy the sound file temporary to the device internal storage and use these path to set ringtone.